# Changing one element in array of objects changes all elements, c#, how do I assign objects by value

Tags: c#, reference

I'm new to c#, and I think I'm confused about how to assign objects by value rather than reference.
In the following code, I have a constructor taking a default object for the posGrid to be filled with. I want these all to be merely copies of the default object, but when I change one, they all change. I assume this is because I'm initializing the array with references to the object, but how do I assign them just the value?

```cs
public Grid (int width, int height, Unit defaultUnit)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    posGrid = new Unit [height, width];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int u = 0; u < width; u++)
            posGrid[y, u] = defaultUnit;
}
```

Comment: Assign a `new Unit()` with default values? It's common to have an empty constructor that creates an instance with default properties values. Or a constructor that builds a new instance based on an existing one.

Comment: Assuming `Unit` is a class, there is nothing you can do to "specify" that you want to pass it by value, because (as you've called out), `defaultUnit` *is a reference*. You need to create new instances of `Unit` using values such that you consider the new instances to have the same "value" as `defaultUnit`. There are a number of patterns you could use to do this, such as a copy constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor

Answer (score 0):

**Variable types**

Variables like int, long are value types and have it's own memory space and contains the value.

**Reference types**

Variable values of string, class .. are not directly stored. The value is stored in a other memory space and a pointer stores this adress and is pointing to it.

**Solution**

So for your problem you have so create a new Unit based on the values of defaultUnit.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could solve this problem.

The simplest way is to make `Unit` a struct:

```
struct Unit { ... }
```

Since `structs` are value types, a copy of `Unit` is automatically created when you assign it to something, as opposed to the reference being copied. However, there might be some features of classes that you want `Unit` to have (e.g. having a base class), in which case you need another method.

---

Alternatively, you can add a `CreateCopy` method:

```
public Unit CreateCopy() {
    Unit copy = new Unit();
    copy.Property1 = this.Property1;
    copy.Property2 = this.Property2;
    // etc
    return copy;
}
```

And call it when you create the array:

```
posGrid = new Unit [height, width];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    for (int u = 0; u < width; u++)
        posGrid[y, u] = defaultUnit.CreateCopy(); // <----
```

You can also achieve this by implementing `ICloneable`.

---

A third method is to have the constructor of `Grid` accept all the data needed to create the unit as parameters, instead of the `Unit` object itself. And then the constructor can create the `Unit` objects on its own.

```
public Grid (int width, int height, SomeType defaultUnitProperty1, SomeType defaultUnitProperty2)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    posGrid = new Unit [height, width];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int u = 0; u < width; u++)
            posGrid[y, u] = new Unit(defaultUnitProperty1, defaultUnitProperty2);
}
```